# Google Chrome browser everything looking tiny DPI issue?

Tags: google-chrome, resolution, high-dpi

Everything looks fine in Firefox and IE. But in Chrome everything looks very tiny, seems DPI has changed to 160.

Please help me fix the font, overall look of Chrome to make bigger. Im using 1920x1080 resolution, my laptop has a 4K screen. Lenovo Y50. Its a windows 8.1 OS.

Below are same resolution comparison btw Chrome and Firefox.

[image: Chrome v37 default zoom]

[image: Firefox default zoom]

Comment: You need to increase the default page zoom to 125% or more (settings > show advanced settings)

Comment: i cannot do that, since i need Chrome in default DPI settings to debug my web development needs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no fix other than reducing resolution.

Or better install Chrome 64bit BETA, which works fine :)